# ajax, send data to specific function in a file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an `ajax` request using jquery.

this is my code:

```
 $(".del-link").click(function() {
    var del = confirm("sure you want to delete?");
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');

}).change(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var del = $("#del_input_" + ID).val();
    var dataString = 'id=' + ID;
    $("#status_" + ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />');
    console.log(dataString);

    if (del == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../inc/deleteRow.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {

                $("#del_" + ID).html(del);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('not deleted');
    }

});
```

I am sending the request to `../inc/deleteRow.php` url.
in that url are several functions.
how do I send the `data` content to a specific function in that file?

edited:

this is the content of the `deleteRow.php` file:
as you can see there are several functions

```
    <?php


if($_POST['id'])
{
$update = new User();
$update->update($_POST['id'], $_POST['lead_status'], $_POST['lead_comment']);
}


{
$update = new User();
$update->updatecall($_POST['id'], $_POST['lead_status'], $_POST['lead_comment']);
}


$delete_row = new User();
$delete_row->delete_row($_POST['id']);




?>
```

Comment: you need to catch the request in the php file using `$_POST` and pass the variables as an argument to that function

Comment: @DavSev: Um, no there aren't...  There are several lines of code, yes.  All of which will be executed in this request.  But there are no separate functions here.  The logic of this PHP code doesn't make much sense to me.  You're creating a new `User`, then updating it.  Then creating a new `User` again, then updating it in some slightly different way?  Then creating *another* new `User` and deleting it?

Comment: As i understand from you answer below I will have to locate each function call in a different file?

Comment: @DavSev: Not *necessarily*, as with anything it depends.  You certainly *can* have multiple operations in a single PHP file, especially if those operations are on the same "record of data" and differentiate only by whether they are an select, insert, update, or delete.  You could use the different HTTP verbs (take a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`) to determine which of those operations to perform on that record.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't know anything about the server-side code.

In the *server-side* code (PHP in this case) you would respond to the request given the information provided in the request.  So given the state of the request being made (the URL, the HTTP verb, most likely the combination of POST values in your case, etc.) the logic in your PHP code would determine what to do.

Ideally you wouldn't have a single URL which does many things.  Instead, you'd have separate URLs (or "resources") which each do one thing (or one small related subset of things).  Preferably something intuitively named.

But any way you look at it, you don't "call a PHP function" from JavaScript.  You send an HTTP request, just as you're already doing.  Then in your server-side code you would respond to that HTTP request using whatever logic your application needs to use.

Comment: That is what i  do so far... but i have many ajax requests and each is linked to a different file. I was sure there was a solution I am not aware about... thank you